# c program recursive function odd

Tags: c, function, recursion, functional-programming

I need a **recursive function** in **C**, that checks/compare the sum of values(integers) in odd positions, with the sum of values in even positions of an array. Also print(inside the function) the bigger sum!

Like:

```
printf("\nThe bigger sum is %d. \n evensum = %d , oddsum = %d \n",bigger, evensum, oddsum);
```

Suppose that array has 8 positions and we fill it from main() with random values.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4


int checksum(int matrix[], int position, int sum1, int sum2); 

int main(void)
{
    int mat[N];
    int i,j;

    printf("\nEnter the %d numbers:\n", N); 

      for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
      {
        printf("%2d> ",i);
        scanf("%d", &mat[i]);
      }

      checksum(mat, 0, 0, 0);       


}

int checksum(int m[], int pos, int s1, int s2){

if(pos<N){
    if(pos==0){
            s1 = m[pos];    
            checksum(m, pos+1, s1, s2);         
        }else{
            if(pos%2){
                return s1 + checksum(m, pos+1, s1, s2);     

            }else{
                return s2 + checksum(m, pos+1, s1, s2);                         
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should try to write that program yourself. If you have concrete problems post your code and ask for guidance.

Comment: i tried this: http://pastie.org/1706480

Comment: You are asking stackoverflow to do your homework? Wow. Just wow. -1.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what recursion is? I think you got it the other way around. That screenshot is iterative.

Comment: @tyler So, who deleted your answer?

Comment: I did because I did not realize it was homework at the time I posted it. I'll be more than glad to still help you, but I won't undelete it. Now, do you mean recursion or iteration? It appears you want iteration but I just need to make sure.

Comment: Lesson to all newcomers: Paste your code _here_, and people will help. Paste your code elsewhere, and the downvotes fly fast and free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides all the fun they picked at you, I understand you was honest tagging "homework". What I'm about to show you is your solution. To make the most of this, you should understand it. If not, you are just fooling yourself. I really hope this can help you in other ways than just a homework done.

You still need to fulfill the vector with random values, and to print the bigger. But this is piece of cake. The recursion can be made like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int sum(int *x, int n, int odd)
{

    if(odd==-1)
    {
        printf("odd = %d, even = %d\n", sum(x, n, 1), sum(x, n, 0));
        return 0;
    }

    if(n%2!=odd)
        return sum(x, n+1, odd);

    if(n>=MAX)
        return 0;

    return x[n]+sum(x, n+1, odd);
}



int main(void)
{
    int x[MAX]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    sum(x, 0, -1);

    return 0;
}
```

For one thing your question lacks... If you read the definition pausing your mouse cursor at the tag homework, you will read "and show sufficient effort".

So, please, after adapting the code as you need, how about you show the final answer here as a token of your effort to learn c language? ;)

Take care!
Beco.

Comment: After reading your code I noted you used forward recursion. Here is an example more like your first intuition: http://pastebin.com/UQEeRi7K Now, if you debug both recursions, what is the main difference between them and the direction they move information?

Comment: The main difference is: *seven = *seven + m[pos] and *sodd= *sodd + m[pos].The previous sum with the current pos value and the final printf.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Actually the main difference when understanding the path followed is that one is adding while calling functions, the other is adding while returning.